# Error deploying a mybatis-truts application

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat6, mybatis

We have a Java application that we deploy using .war files on tomcat server. The war is copied on the webapp directory (tomcat stopped) and then we start the server. We have several scripts that automate the process and we have deploying on development-backup and production servers without problems until two days ago... Then we were able to deploy on development machines, but in backup and production (ovh machines) we received an exception starting tomcat:

```
### Error building SqlSession.
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error building SqlSession.
### Cause: org.apache.ibatis.builder.BuilderException: Error creating document instance.  Cause: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.build(SqlSessionFactoryBuilder.java:39)
```

Redeploying old .war works fine, but new .war produces all the time this exception. We have spend lot of hours trying to figure out what is wrong, but the same .war that does not work on production work on a development machine and (this is incredible) if we deploy using another name for the war (just renaming the .war file) the application works.. But we need the application to work using this specific context name.

Please... help!

Answer (score 0):

Finaly solved...

The main reason was the checking url from haproxy that in this version uses database, so, while the context are deploying haproxy try to load this url and causes several initializations on mybatis...

Changing the url haproxy query solves the problem, but I'm not sure the good way to avoid the initialization problem under load.